# How to modify every character in a NSString then put it in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, rsa

A string value is entered by the user and is stored. Every character in that string is placed into an array. Each element of the array is modified; (the ascii value is found of the character and then a calculation is conducted to change the ascii value). The newly modified number is added into the array by replacing the element it had previously modified. Code for this can be shown here:

```
NSString *toEncryptMessage = _message.text;
    NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[toEncryptMessage length]];
    int encrypted_power;
    int encrypted_number;
    for (int i = 0; i <[toEncryptMessage length]; i++){

        NSString* subchar = [toEncryptMessage 
substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        if (subchar) [characters addObject:subchar];
        unichar chr = [subchar characterAtIndex:0];
        encrypted_power = pow(chr,e);
        encrypted_number = encrypted_power % N;
        NSLog(@"ascii value %d", chr);

        [characters replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber 
    numberWithInt: encrypted_number]];

    }
    NSLog(@"%@", characters);
}
```

However, the problem I am experiencing is that 'encrypted_power' is a negative number. Encrypted_power is the ascii value to the power of 'e', where e = 7 (previously calculated elsewhere).

I have inserted a breakpoint at the 'pow' line and inserted 'hi' to be modified:

```
e = 7
toEncryptMessage = (NSTaggedPointerString *)    @"hi" 0xa000000000069682
characters  __NSArrayM *    @"1 element"    0x00006080002513d0
encrypted_power = (int) -2147483648
encrypted_number = (int) -2
i = 0
```

The next character is then attempted to be modified:

```
encrypted_power = (int) -2147483648
encrypted_number = (int) -2
i = (int) 1
subchar = (NSTaggedPointerString) @"i"
chr unichar U+0068 u'i'
```

In the log is this:

```
Prototype2[56766:1730834] (
"-2",
"-2"
)
2017-10-12 16:54:21.766561 Prototype2[56766:1730834] [Common] 
_BSMachError: port 7417; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to 
insert COPY_SEND"
2017-10-12 16:54:21.767494 Prototype2[56766:1730834] [Common] 
_BSMachError: port 7417; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to 
deallocate send right"
```

Any help is good, thank you.

Comment: Try `encrypted_power` and `encrypted_number` as `NSInteger`, not `int`. I'm wondering if you are not exceeding `int` limit? What's the value of `N` (to reproduce).

Comment: Changing int to NSInteger solved it! Im not 100% sure why though. Thank you! and N was the product of two prime numbers, however, it changes every time i run the script so now I do not know what it was in this example. Thank you @Larme

Comment: You are over exceeding the limit of `int`. `INT_MIN` is "-2147483648" (in my simulator, 64 bits so)